# Parallel Tasks & lock local variables

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing, locking, task

I'm new in multithreading programming and I have some questions about it. I'm developing a scheduled job that loads a .xls that every row with data needs to be validated and after open a request in a application, and I'm implementing multithreading to process every row, aiming win some performance.

In my job I have something like this example:

```
public class Job
{
    private readonly IUserBLO _userBLO;
    private readonly IRequestBLO _requestBLO;
    private readonly object _lockerSheet;

    public Job()
    {
        _userBLO = Factory.CreateInstance("UserBLO");
        _requestBLO = Factory.CreateInstance("RequestBLO");
        _lockerSheet = new object();
    }

    public void ProcessJob(BinaryWriter binary)
    {
        using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(binary))
        {
            var sheet = package.Workbook.Worksheet[1];

            var rows = Enumerable.Range(sheet.Dimensions.Start.Row, sheet.Dimensions.End.Row);

            Parallel.ForEach(rows, row =>
            {
                try
                {
                    var excelData = GetExcelData(sheet, row);

                    ValidadeData(excelData);

                    _requestBLO.OpenRequestByExcelData(excelData);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    LogError(ex);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public List<string> GetExcelData(ExcelWorksheet sheet, int row)
    {
        var excelData = new List<string>();

        for (int i = sheet.Dimensions.Start.Column; i <= sheet.Dimensions.End.Column; i++)
        {
            lock (_lockerSheet)
            {
                var cellValue = sheet.Cells[row, i].Text;
            }

            excelData.Add(cellValue);
        }

        return excelData;
    }

    public void ValidadeData(List<string> excelData)
    {
        var userLogin = excelData.First();

        var user = _userBLO.FindByLogin(userLogin);

        if (user == null)
            throw new Exception("User not found!");
    }
}
```

When I was coding, I had some issues that when I tried to get the value from sheet in a random position, sometimes, it returned empty, even though this position had value. After some search in google, I tried to use a locker in the moment I was getting the value from sheet, and apparently worked!

```
lock (_lockerSheet)
{
    var cellValue = sheet.Cells[row, i].Text;
}
```

After this situation, I had some questions:

1. For every "local" variable that will be parallel used in the tasks needs to be locked, even if that variable is readonly. I'm correct?
2. If the question above is true, do I need to use a locker in the _userBLO and _requestBLO variables, which are interfaces that contais some specific methods?
3. If the first question is false, do I just need use a locker if the variable will recive some value in task? When do I really need to use a locker?

PS.: Sorry for my bad english! Brazilian here! :)

Comment: I figured my answer would make more sense in a comment since Henk summarized it better, but [check out this article](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx#_Locking). It will help you understand why thread safety is important.

Comment: Wait, are you trying to use Excel objects as though they support free threaded marshalling?  Do they?  I thought Excel was *apartment*, not *rental* or *free*, but it has been fifteen years since I last tried to write multithreaded code against Excel. I might be misremembering. If you're trying to rental-thread in parallel, first, that's going to be super slow and destroy your parallelism gains, and two, Excel's going to crash.  Can you explain your threading model in more detail?

Comment: @EricLippert - ExcelPackage is Open XML, I don't think there is an Excel instance running here.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: Thanks for that note. No worries then -- assuming that Open XML is free threaded then you don't have a problem with the marshaller. However you will still be destroying parallelism.  **If you need to put a lock in your parallel step then it is probably not parallelizable in the first place**.

Comment: It is an older package promising "Spreadsheet OOXML on the server". And I just learned that FireFox has [red-listed CodePlex](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=excelpackage).  )-:

Comment: @EricLippert well, I didn't question this to myself. It's an interesting point, I will search for this. However, technically, even though do I put a lock in some step, all tasks that I instance will run in parallel?

Comment: Locks *prevent* parallelism. Locks are like putting traffic lights onto freeways; there are fewer crashes, but traffic goes a lot slower. If you're adding locks to make parallelism work, something is probably wrong.